# aspx.net gives blank error message

Tags: asp.net

What could this blank error message mean? I get it randomly in my LOGS. I am using non-cookie sessions.  it occurs randomly in all aspx files..

code handler outputs:
            objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException()
            Server.ClearError()

```
Error Message: & objErr.Message.ToString())
Stack Trace: & objErr.StackTrace.ToString())
```

output

```
    Error Message:
    Stack Trace:
    at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath) at
  System.Web.CachedPathData.GetVirtualPathData(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean 
 permitPathsOutsideApp) at System.Web.HttpContext.GetFilePathData() at 
 System.Web.HttpContext.GetConfigurationPathData() at
 System.Web.HttpContext.get_ImpersonationToken() at
 System.Web.ClientImpersonationContext.Start(HttpContext context, Boolean throwOnError) at
 System.Web.HttpApplication.ThreadContext.Enter(Boolean setImpersonationContext) at 
 System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean setImpersonationContext) at 
 System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this an inner exception that you are seeing?

regarding `ToString()`:

> If there is no error message or if it is an empty string (""), then no error message is returned. The name of the inner exception and the stack trace are returned only if they are not a null reference

[Here's a link](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~lok/csharp/refdocs/System/types/Exception.html)

Comment: I am using this now:
            objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException()

objErr.innerexception does not work..